# Ajax working odd on mobile and touch screen devices

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, validation

I have a dynamic form in my app that can be live edited (adding or removing input fields) but i had a problem on validation when user made some mistake and didn't fill something right all new added fields would be gone and that was very bad because the user had to recreate everything how he had it before.

So to solve that problem i have created an ajax call just to check if validation is fine:

```
// send ajax first to check validation so that the dynamic fields don't disappear
$(document).on('touchstart mousedown', ':submit', function() {
    $('input[name="items"]').val($('.item').length);
    var form = $("form");
    var myMethod = '';
    var myRoute = '';
    var orderId = "<?php if (isset($order->id)) { echo $order->id; } else { echo false;} ?>";

    if( $(this).val() === 'Make new order' && !orderId){
        myMethod = 'post'
        myRoute = '/orders'

    } else {
        myMethod = 'post';
        myRoute = '/orders/edit/' + orderId;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: myMethod,
        url: myRoute,
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{csrf_token()}}" },
        data: form.serializeArray(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log('validation success!');
        },
        error: function(data) {
            var errors = data.responseJSON;
            var errorsArr = [];
            for (error in errors) {
                errorsArr.push(errors[error][0]);
            }
            bootbox.alert(errorsArr.join("<br>"));
            console.log(errors);

        }
    });
});
```

and in my controller i have this:

```
public function store(OrdersForm $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){ 

        return response()->json();

    } else {

        // save all...
    }
}
```

And the problem is that all works fine on the computer i get the validation messages for both create and edit submits but on tablet and mobile phones all crazy things going on...

I get double validation error on create and on edit i get validation message briefly and it goes away i don't know where to debug this...how can i see what is happening on mobile phone?

Comment: you can use chrome's built-in development tools to emulate (by changing the screen size) a mobile device. from your description, it does sound like your event handling could be an issue. Is touchstart AND mousedown necessary? Because AFAIK you can just have mousedown? This could explain the duplication

Comment: you also appear to overwrite all "submit" functions. if you have any other ajax firing on that page which also causes it to "submit" it will duplicate and act strange. rather bind to just the button that's responsible for submit?

Comment: thank you for the tip with chrome debugging i get the same problems, but now at least i can see that

Comment: OK the double message comes because of the touchstart and mousedown...that is clear....now what i don't get is: why do my validation messages go away when i try to submit on edit page

Comment: Now i know ... it is because of the timeout on mobile and touch devices....they have this timeout that is enough to make thing don't work as i want....how can i solve this?

Comment: Not entirely sure it's a timeout issue as I can't think of a reason why it would be different for mobile vs desktop. It could be that bootbox can be the culprit by closing the messages on submit? I know some of those plugins exit when they lose focus

Comment: It's because there are 2 things going on when you click submit....if i would delete ajax, the submit button when pressed does his job as it should (validation, try to save). But with ajax: ajax should go first to check validation. (i am not saving the data with ajax, you can see that in my controller, just return the response) and the problem is with touch devices that my ajax doesn't go first...i hope you understand this better now

Comment: OK, i have finally solved the problem. I had to change the Form Submit button to a normal button so that it doesn't submit the form and then i added `$("form").submit();` in ajax success and that's it... if someone was following this you can make an answer from last few comments and i will accept it

Comment: Oh that's true, I totally didn't think of that off the bat, your submit will fire anyway because you don't have e.preventDefault() or a manual submit function like you did. Glad you got sorted bud!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is firing like that because you need to change the submit button to a regular button, and then fire the form submission manually when the AJAX request you sent to check for validation, comes back as a success.